# include path in Laravel

Tags: laravel, path, include, slash

I want to include a path into my master.blade.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = '{{ asset('assets/plugins/') }}';</script>
```

The problem is that the path is not recognized correctly. 
how should I specify the path that the slash is accepted? [image: between plugin and the following word is missing the slash]

Comment: Do you have an `assets` folder inside `public`?

Comment: Yes, there are my css and js files

Comment: so in your `public` folder, there is a folder called `assets` yeah? So the structure is `public/assets/style.css` or whatever? The error is saying that the file doesn't exist. Put up a screenshot of the public directory/anything else helpful

Comment: Also, looking at the error the slash after plugins isn't displaying. Sure it's not just cached or you've missed the trailing slash in your application but added it here?

Comment: Why your code is irrelevant in your console error? Because you're just using the folder, not the exact js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at your console errors, you can see that it fails for resources

`/assets/pluginsboots...js/` (note missing `/`)

when it should have been

`/assets/plugins/boots...js/`

[asset()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L202) trims `/` from the beginning and the end.

You have to write your `var plugin_path` a bit different

```
<script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = '{{ asset('assets/plugins') }}/';</script>
```